# if you accidentally merged your branch with staging, will reverting it damage the history

Tags: git

i pushed a branch to the main, instead of staging, and then i reverted this change.

Has this left any lasting effects such as changed the history or are all negative effects removed?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you did. How did you "revert this change"? What were the exact commands you executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has this left any lasting effects

Yes. A `git revert` of a merge commit changes the state but not the topology (history). Thus, although the `main` branch looks correct as to its current state, your branch's commits now cannot be merged into `main` ever again in future, because they are still part of `main`'s history. That may or may not be a problem; it all depends.

(This is the problem so well discussed at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).